# How can I call an extension method from within a C# Console program?

Tags: c#

I created this extension method:

```
public static class Helpers
{
    private static string GetUntil(this string input, char[] delimiters)
    {
        if (input == null || input.IndexOfAny(delimiters) == -1)
            return input;
        else
            return input.Split(delimiters)[0];
    }
}
```

and I am trying to call it here:

```
public partial class Program
{

    private static (string, string) GetM(string kanji, string hiragana)
    {

        var jm = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(JMdictHiraganaSelector).InnerText;
        var jm2 = jmDictHiragana.GetUntil(new char[] { ' ', '[' });
```

But it's giving me an error message on  GetUntil saying:

> Error CS1106: Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class (CS1106) (data-1)

Can anyone point out to me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The extension method needs to be public, not private. You have to be "using" the namespace as well.

Comment: `public static string GetUntil(this string input, char[] delimiters) {...}`, please, note `public`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Console Programms have no impact on the existence or working of a Extension Method. They are a C# language feature.

As others have pointed out, it needs to be public. Note that Extension Methods are little more then Syntax Sugar for static functions, that take a instance. They in no way get access to private or protected stuff.

They are also only a fallback if you can not inherit the class. This was a particular issue faced with string, as that class is marked as "sealed".